# If/Else or not contains in Azure DevOps YAML for dynamically setting build config?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I want one yaml if at all possible. However, the circumstances dictate that this single yaml will have auto triggers for certain branches (develop/release), but still can be manually built by any other branch qa wishes to test (i.e. they want to test a feature branch, they can build it using this yaml).

I need to dynamically set the buildconfig property.

I have:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
      - Release/*

pool:
  name: 'my-agent'

variables:
  isRelease: $[contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'release')]

if {{$(isRelease)}}:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
```

// if not release then set build config to '`Debug`' but I'm struggling with the syntax. I can't find a `not` operator working well, or `notIn`...can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would negate the `if` condition to get the "debug" condition. Also, there is no `else`, so you have to stack them:

```yaml
${{ if variables.isRelease }}:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
${{ if not(variables.isRelease) }}:
  buildConfiguration: 'NotRelease'
```

Answer (score 1):

Now we have [if else expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2021/sprint-192-update#new-yaml-conditional-expressions) and we can use it as follows:

```yaml
${{ if variables.isRelease }}:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
${{ else }}:
  buildConfiguration: 'NotRelease'
```